# How do I display an image saved within a file location in a new window by clicking a gridview link? A Terms Popup (modal) should display in between

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms, modal-dialog

Ok for a couple of weeks I have been stuck on a problem with one of my branches legacy applications.
    I have a gridview and when I click on a link in the gridview I get a relevant image displayed within a new window. A new requirement has come in requesting that after clicking on the new window, the user should be displayed a "Terms of Use" pop up which they need to agree. After agreeing, the image should load in the new window as before.

I tried creating a popup with a modal.dialog using a bit of jquery and a div and I can get this to show. However any attempt I have made to open the image from this pop up has not worked. I think the index of the gridview gets lost when displaying the modal pop up.

The application is about 12 years old (waaaay before me). It was developed in c# and asp.net web forms.
I am new to stack. Apologies about formatting. The filestream code was in there for ages. Would there be a better way of doing this?  Thank you for any help in advance.

So the user clicks on link within gridview -> A pop up displays the terms with an Agree button and ideally a cancel button too. User agrees and the popup displays image.

'''<%--button in gridview.--%>

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnOpenObject" runat="server" Text="View"  OnClick="OpenObjectSelect_Click"
        AlternateText="Opens Object in a new window" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target= '_blank';" ToolTip="Opens in a new window"
        CssClass="btnHyperLinkEnabled">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

'''<%--modal pop up.--%>

```
<div id="ModalMessage" title="testWindow" class="divAcceptWindow" style="display: none;">
<label style="font-weight: bold" class="boldCentral">Copying and Copyright Declaration</label>
<br />
This declaration has been issued under rule 5(3).
I declare that: blah blah…
<input type="button" id="okButton" value="I Agree" name="okButton" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //script to call popup
    function showdialog() {
        $("#ModalMessage").dialog({ modal: true });
        $("#ModalMessage").dialog({ width: 500 });
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    //script to show image from serverside
    $('#okButton').click(function () {
        $('#ModalMessage').dialog('close');
        var dataToSend = { MethodName: 'IAgree' };
        var options =
        {
            data: dataToSend,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
        }
        $.ajax(options);
    });
</script>
```

'''//c# (code behind)

'''//Gridview link button click event

```
protected void OpenObjectSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton b = (LinkButton)sender;
        int miIndex = Convert.ToInt32(b.CommandArgument);
        LocalSearch.DetailPosition = miIndex;
        miArchiveItemId = LocalSearch.ArchiveItems[LocalSearch.DetailPosition].ArchiveItemId;
        //call popup
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "showdialog()", true);
    }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //hook of jquery button click with method. This is hit after clicking I agree on pop up.
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)            {
            if (Request.Form["MethodName"] == "IAgree") // same Method Name that we are specifying on client side
            {
                Agree();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

'''// Get information relating to image to pass to file stream

```
private void Agree()
    {
        ArchiveItem myArchiveItem = new ArchiveItem();
        miArchiveItemId = Trunks;
        if (miArchiveItemId > 0)
        {
            //Retrieve data from DB.
            myArchiveItem = mysearchMediator.GetArchiveItemByID(miArchiveItemId);
        }
        DigitalObjectLink(myArchiveItem);
    }

    //Display the image using a file stream.
    //Code works to display image without the file modal

public void DigitalObjectLink(ArchiveItem myArchiveItem)
    {
        LinkButton OpenObject = new LinkButton();

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            OpenObject = (LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("btnOpenObject");
            OpenObject.OnClientClick = "aspnetForm.target ='_blank';";
        }
        try
        {
            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageFilePath"] + '\\' + myArchiveItem.RelativeFolderPath +
               '\\' + myArchiveItem.FileName;

            //string path = "C:" + '\\' + "Temp" + '\\' + myArchiveItem.FileName;

            FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            byte[] ar = new byte[(int)fs.Length];


            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + myArchiveItem.FileName);
            Response.ContentType = "application/octectstream";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:showdialog('" + path + "'); ", true);

            fs.Read(ar, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            fs.Close();
            Response.BinaryWrite(ar);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
        catch
        {
            /*
            ** Hide Navigation & GridView & Show File Not Found Panel
            */
            OpenObject.OnClientClick = "aspnetForm.target ='_self';";
            this.NavigationControl1.Visible = false;
            this.NavigationControl2.Visible = false;
            this.GridView1.Visible = false;
            lblFileNotFound.CssClass = "SearchResultsCount";
            btnContactUs.Text = "Please contact PRONI quoting reference: " + myArchiveItem.Reference;

        }
    }
```